# Flask flask_uploads.UploadNotAllowed error

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads, flask-reuploaded

I am using flask to handle image uploads and whenever I upload a jpg, jpeg, or png the program I made is able to handle the upload. However, whenever uploading a .jfif image the program returns the error `flask_uploads.UploadNotAllowed`. Thanks for any help in advance!

The code the program is having an issue with is:

```
file_name = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
```

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 

    "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
        response = self.handle_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\OCR - Copy\OCRWebsite\app.py", line 421, in upload
        file_name = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_uploads.py", line 416, in save
        raise UploadNotAllowed()
    flask_uploads.UploadNotAllowed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask-Uploads always throwing 'UploadNotAllowed' error even with no constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884903/flask-uploads-always-throwing-uploadnotallowed-error-even-with-no-constraints)

Comment: No, that is a different reason

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the standard `IMAGES` set:

https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded/blob/f05077b085393dbc607c01b8daff1b3a8b2dbf0b/src/flask_uploads/extensions.py#L29

This set does not allow `.jfif` files.

However, such a set is really only a Python set, so you can create and use your own, or just update the existing one.

`IMAGES.update(".jfif")`

Comment: Hello, where would I use this code in my program?

Comment: As said above, you can update the `IMAGES` set just after you imported it, where you use also create your app and do the `photos = UploadSet("photos", IMAGES)` or instead of importing `IMAGES` you just create one, also before creating the `UploadSet`.