# Uploading an XML file is causing Flask to generate an error

Tags: python, xml, flask

I am writing a backend Python appliation that will eventually be used to post to currently undefined endpoints. While I wait for requirements to be defined, I have tried creating two endpoints using Flask just to test posting to a server.

Using the below code will generate the error at the bottom of this post.

My code works fine for files with an extension such as a .txt, .wav, .mp3. I have not tested my flask server implementation with all possible file extensions, just with file extension that I know I might have to upload.

I have tried looking at the code for Flask and Werkzeug to find what might be causing the issue, but I am unable to find anything useful. Is there a config file or a parameter that I can set to allow an XML file to be uploaded?

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, AUDIO, TEXT

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'xml', 'wav'}

app = Flask(__name__)

audio = UploadSet('audio', AUDIO)
docs = UploadSet('docs', TEXT)

app.config['UPLOADED_AUDIO_DEST'] = 'static/audio'
app.config['UPLOADED_DOCS_DEST'] = 'static/docs'

configure_uploads(app, (audio, docs))

def allowed_file(filename):
   return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/upload-audio', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_audio():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'audiofile' in request.files:
        filename = audio.save(request.files['audiofile'])
        return "Audio file: '{}' uploaded successfully!".format(filename)
    return ''' <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data> <input type=file name=audiofile> <input type=submit value=Upload> </form> '''

@app.route('/upload-xml', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_xml():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'xmlfile' in request.files:
        filename = docs.save(request.files['xmlfile'])
        return "XML file: '{}' uploaded successfully!".format(filename)
    return ''' <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data> <input type=file name=xmlfile> <input type=submit value=Upload> </form> '''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And my output logs are:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Server: Werkzeug/3.0.1 Python/3.11.2
Date: Mon, 11 Mar 2024 18:23:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 16489
Connection: close

<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <title>flask_uploads.exceptions.UploadNotAllowed
 // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon"
        href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=console.png">
    <script src="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=debugger.js"></script>
    <script>
      var CONSOLE_MODE = false,
          EVALEX = true,
          EVALEX_TRUSTED = false,
          SECRET = "h1E...lX8";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #fff">
    <div class="debugger">
<h1>UploadNotAllowed</h1>
<div class="detail">
  <p class="errormsg">flask_uploads.exceptions.UploadNotAllowed
</p>
</div>
<h2 class="traceback">Traceback <em>(most recent call last)</em></h2>
<div class="traceback">
  <h3></h3>
  <ul><li><div class="frame" id="frame-140047734761376">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1488</em>,
      in <code class="function">__call__</code></h4>
  <div class="source "><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">    </span>) -&gt; cabc.Iterable[bytes]:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>&#34;&#34;&#34;The WSGI server calls the Flask application object as the</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>WSGI application. This calls :meth:`wsgi_app`, which can be</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>wrapped to apply middleware.</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>&#34;&#34;&#34;</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">        </span>return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
<span class="ws">        </span>       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140047734764400">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1466</em>,
      in <code class="function">wsgi_app</code></h4>
  <div class="source "><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>try:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>ctx.push()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>response = self.full_dispatch_request()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>except Exception as e:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>error = e</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">                </span>response = self.handle_exception(e)
<span class="ws">                </span>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>except:  # noqa: B001</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>error = sys.exc_info()[1]</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>raise</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>return response(environ, start_response)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>finally:</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140047734764544">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">1463</em>,
      in <code class="function">wsgi_app</code></h4>
  <div class="source "><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>ctx = self.request_context(environ)</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>error: BaseException | None = None</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>try:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>try:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>ctx.push()</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">                </span>response = self.full_dispatch_request()
<span class="ws">                </span>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>except Exception as e:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>error = e</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>response = self.handle_exception(e)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>except:  # noqa: B001</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>error = sys.exc_info()[1]</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140047734764688">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">872</em>,
      in <code class="function">full_dispatch_request</code></h4>
  <div class="source "><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>request_started.send(self, _async_wrapper=self.ensure_sync)</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>rv = self.preprocess_request()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>if rv is None:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">                </span>rv = self.dispatch_request()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>except Exception as e:</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">            </span>rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
<span class="ws">            </span>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>return self.finalize_request(rv)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>def finalize_request(</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>self,</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>rv: ft.ResponseReturnValue | HTTPException,</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140047734764832">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">870</em>,
      in <code class="function">full_dispatch_request</code></h4>
  <div class="source "><pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>try:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>request_started.send(self, _async_wrapper=self.ensure_sync)</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>rv = self.preprocess_request()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>if rv is None:</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">                </span>rv = self.dispatch_request()
<span class="ws">                </span>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>except Exception as e:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>return self.finalize_request(rv)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>def finalize_request(</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140047734764976">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">855</em>,
      in <code class="function">dispatch_request</code></h4>
  <div class="source "><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>and req.method == &#34;OPTIONS&#34;</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>):</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>return self.make_default_options_response()</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span># otherwise dispatch to the handler for that endpoint</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>view_args: dict[str, t.Any] = req.view_args  # type: ignore[assignment]</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">        </span>return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
<span class="ws">        </span>       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>def full_dispatch_request(self) -&gt; Response:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>&#34;&#34;&#34;Dispatches the request and on top of that performs request</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>pre and postprocessing as well as HTTP exception catching and</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>error handling.</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140047734765120">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/home/steve/flask_endpoints.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">29</em>,
      in <code class="function">upload_xml</code></h4>
  <div class="source "><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">    </span>return &#39;&#39;&#39; &lt;form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data&gt; &lt;input type=file name=audiofile&gt; &lt;input type=submit value=Upload&gt; &lt;/form&gt; &#39;&#39;&#39;</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span>@app.route(&#39;/upload-xml&#39;, methods=[&#39;GET&#39;, &#39;POST&#39;])</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span>def upload_xml():</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">    </span>if request.method == &#39;POST&#39; and &#39;xmlfile&#39; in request.files:</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">        </span>filename = docs.save(request.files[&#39;xmlfile&#39;])
<span class="ws">        </span>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>return &#34;XML file: &#39;{}&#39; uploaded successfully!&#34;.format(filename)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>return &#39;&#39;&#39; &lt;form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data&gt; &lt;input type=file name=xmlfile&gt; &lt;input type=submit value=Upload&gt; &lt;/form&gt; &#39;&#39;&#39;</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span>if __name__ == &#39;__main__&#39;:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">    </span>app.run(debug=True)</pre></div>
</div>

<li><div class="frame" id="frame-140047734765408">
  <h4>File <cite class="filename">"/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_uploads/flask_uploads.py"</cite>,
      line <em class="line">322</em>,
      in <code class="function">save</code></h4>
  <div class="source "><pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>if storage.filename is None:</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">            </span>raise ValueError(&#34;Filename must not be empty!&#34;)</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>basename = self.get_basename(storage.filename)</pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line before"><span class="ws">        </span>if not self.file_allowed(storage, basename):</pre>
<pre class="line current"><span class="ws">            </span>raise UploadNotAllowed()
<span class="ws">            </span>^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws"></span> </pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">        </span>if name:</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>if name.endswith(&#39;.&#39;):</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">                </span>basename = name + extension(basename)</pre>
<pre class="line after"><span class="ws">            </span>else:</pre></div>
</div>
</ul>
  <blockquote>flask_uploads.exceptions.UploadNotAllowed
</blockquote>
</div>

<div class="plain">
    <p>
      This is the Copy/Paste friendly version of the traceback.
    </p>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="code" readonly>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &#34;/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 1488, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File &#34;/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 1466, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File &#34;/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File &#34;/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 872, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File &#34;/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File &#34;/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py&#34;, line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File &#34;/home/steve/flask_endpoints.py&#34;, line 29, in upload_xml
    filename = docs.save(request.files[&#39;xmlfile&#39;])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File &#34;/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_uploads/flask_uploads.py&#34;, line 322, in save
    raise UploadNotAllowed()
flask_uploads.exceptions.UploadNotAllowed
</textarea>
</div>
<div class="explanation">
  The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application.  You can now
  look at the traceback which led to the error.  <span class="nojavascript">
  If you enable JavaScript you can also use additional features such as code
  execution (if the evalex feature is enabled), automatic pasting of the
  exceptions and much more.</span>
</div>
      <div class="footer">
        Brought to you by <strong class="arthur">DON'T PANIC</strong>, your
        friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pin-prompt">
      <div class="inner">
        <h3>Console Locked</h3>
        <p>
          The console is locked and needs to be unlocked by entering the PIN.
          You can find the PIN printed out on the standard output of your
          shell that runs the server.
        <form>
          <p>PIN:
            <input type=text name=pin size=14>
            <input type=submit name=btn value="Confirm Pin">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<!--

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1488, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1466, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/steve/flask_endpoints.py", line 29, in upload_xml
    filename = docs.save(request.files['xmlfile'])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/steve/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_uploads/flask_uploads.py", line 322, in save
    raise UploadNotAllowed()
flask_uploads.exceptions.UploadNotAllowed


-->
```

EDIT:

For those that are interested in exactly what did to my code to resolve the issue, I added DATA to the import statement and changed TEXT to DATA and designed my collection of files as DATA.

```
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, AUDIO, **DATA**

docs = UploadSet('docs', **DATA**)
```

This site helped give me a better understanding of Flask.

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884903/flask-uploads-always-throwing-uploadnotallowed-error-even-with-no-constraints

Comment: It seems to me that only files with the extension `.txt` are allowed in `TEXT`. Try `DATA` for structured data files with one of the extensions `.csv`, `.ini`, `.json`, `.plist`, `.xml`, `.yaml`, and `.yml`.

Comment: @Detlef - For some reason I am unable to mark your response as resolving my issues, but I eventually came across the following page which discusses exactly what you are talking about.

https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/

I implemented your suggestion and it worked!!! Thank you!